# Добавление элемента в массив php

Tags: php, база-данных

функция `getSchoolById()` возвращает объект, а функция `getSchoolStaffById()` возвращает массив, как мне добавить объект в массив.

```
function getSchoolById($id)
{
    global $pdo;
    $smtp = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `schools` where id = :id');
    $smtp->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $smtp->execute();
    $school = $smtp->fetchObject();
    $school = json_encode($school);
    $schoolStaff = getSchoolStaffById($id);
    array_push($schoolStaff,$school);
    die( getSchoolStaffById($id));
}

function getSchoolStaffById($id)
{
    global $pdo;
    $smtp = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `school_staff` where school_id = :id');
    $smtp->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $smtp->execute();
    $makes = $smtp->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return(json_encode($makes));
}
```

`array_push()` возвращает такую ошибку

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in D:\OSPanel\domains\lessonsPhp\Homework\work10\bestChoice\api.php on line 61

Comment: Осмысленность этого кода вызывает серьезные сомнения. Зачем используется fetchAll, если запрос возвращает 1 строку? Почему в одном случае мы запрашиваем массив, а в другом - объект? Зачем вообще объединять в одном списке разнородные данные?

Comment: запрос не возвращает 1 строку, а   объединять нужно для ответа на api запрос

Comment: Ну расскажи еще, что запрос `SELECT * FROM schools where id = :id` возвращает больше одной строки. А ответ надо делать более осмысленным. Не в виде списка а в виде ассоциативного массива, чтобы было понятно, в каком элементе какие данные лежат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что функция json_encode имеет тип возвращаемого значения - string.

```
return(json_encode($makes));
```

Подробнее - тут http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Comment: В последнее время стал замечать очень странную манеру копировать в ответ код из вопроса как есть, без изменений, в то время как читатель ждет исправленного кода. Осмысленность такого действия является для меня загадкой.

Comment: А ничего, что я просто указал на строку с ошибкой?